# jQuery - $(window).height() and width() simply wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something really simple: I need the height of my viewport in the browser.

It's around 855 pixels, jQuery tells me it's 497. The error occures in `Firefox and Chrome` (EDIT: Nope just Firefox). The width is also off by the same ratio: It's always `58%` of the real value.

So far I've tried the following: `$(window).height()`, `$(document).height()`, `$('body').height()`

I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my html. I don't know what to do anymore or how to interprete this 58% nonsense.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: To prevent some confusion, there is no scrollbar on my site. This means viewport and document height should be the same, right?

**EDIT 2: I Apparently `Chrome` does give the correct values. This is a `Firefox` issue.**

Comment: Can you post a codepen or fiddle? Have you tried using `$(window).outerHeight()`?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get a codepen or a fiddle. It's a huge project, with dynamically generated content. :/

I just tried `outerHeight` - same result, 497px.

Comment: Without some code or an example we're just going to be speculating. Is there anything that you can show us which may help us to help you find the solution?

Comment: outerHeight is the whole browser window. They've asked for viewport which is innerHeight.

Comment: Can you create a small example with the same problem? It might also help you to isolate the problem.

Comment: You don't have your console open and docked at the bottom of the screen do you?

Comment: Is the JavaScript running within an iframe by any chance?

Comment: No iframe and my firebug/javascript console isn't opened either.

Comment: So provide at least an online link where your issue can be checked

Comment: What does `document.documentElement.clientHeight` return?

Comment: @JPDurham The same 497px - at least in Firefox. I think I'll be doing more googling on the subject.

Comment: I don't know when you're detecting it in your code but there's been a bug where it reports incorrectly before load. So maybe test with window.onload to see if it will report correctly after the window has been loaded.

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem." 

I just answered my own question in a manner that might help someone else who reads this later. But go ahead, close stuff, I know you feel compelled to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, you helped me exclude some possibilities. Apparently the problem was the following: I had zoomed in in Firefox.

Then Firefox somehow gave me the pixels that I could see of the html document instead of the pixels of my screen.

I'm really not sure how to feel about this (considering I really wanted the pixels of my screen.)

Comment: This scabby zoom! You helped me a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? :

```
$(document).outerHeight()
```

And:

```
$(document).outerWidth()
```

Window innerHeight in jQuery

```
$(window).prop('innerHeight')
```

Comment: Once again, they've asked for the viewport height. This is for the whole browser window. innerHeight is for viewport.

Comment: $(window).prop('innerHeight') returned 497, $(window).prop('outerHeight') returned 583. 

Hm. Still not correct.